# Using an if statement in the theme customizer page

Tags: theme-development, ajax, theme-options, theme-customizer

I am slowly but surely chipping away at my first wordpress theme. I tried to make all of the aesthetics have different options, but well categorized so it is not overwhelming.

So in my theme customizer page I have different checkboxes that could distinguish different options for a certain components style. For instance I could have two checkboxes to distinguish what button type the user wants.

So my question is:

How can I automatically uncheck one checkbox if the another in it's group is checked? I figure this will prevent me from having different options for the same element on the page checked and potentially messing something up. I figure if statements are probably the only way to go but I am unsure how to add them since I didn't create the page, it is all done using the theme customizer API.

I am starting to think I should of used an options page instead, even though it is supposed to be a thing of the past and doesn't provide live previews, but it seems like it would add more flexibility.

Comment: It is though, because it uses the theme customizer api. I don't actually write any of the code to create the forms so I don't control it. I add which control I want and link it to a setting. What I really need to know is how can I gain control of the form controls so I can write the logic? Also some groups may need to boxes checked off while the other ones are unchecked. I don't know if radio buttons will help me there.

Comment: Have a look at this, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4991/how-to-use-checkbox-and-radio-button-in-options-page , to toggle multiple checkbox states use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description makes it sound like you need a radio button. Radio buttons by design are exclusive-- only one button per button set can be checked at any one time.

The [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) supports radio boxes, though the documentation for using them is sparse. I had to dig around a bit, and experiment. The key is the second parameter of [`add_control`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control). You need to pass `'type' =>`radio'`and provide a`choices` array for the radio button values.

```
function radio_controls_wpse_117203($wpc) {

  $wpc->add_setting(
    'radio_control_wpse_117203',
    array(
      'default' => 'hi',
    )
  );

  $wpc->add_section(
    'radio_section_wpse_117203',
    array(
      'title' => 'Radio WPSE 117203',
      'description' => 'A holder for our radio buttons.',
    )
  );

  $wpc->add_control(
    'radio_control_wpse_117203',
    array(
      'type' => 'radio',
      'label' => 'Salutation',
      'section' => 'radio_section_wpse_117203',
      'choices' => array(
        'hi' => 'Hi',
        'howdy' => 'Howdy',
      ),
    )
  );

}
add_action('customize_register','radio_controls_wpse_117203');
```

Comment: I modified the customizer to use the radio buttons instead and it really helps. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: It seems that the default value isn't working for me. I am not sure why. It works fine when I change the value in theme customizer and save it. It is only the default value. Do you know why this could be?